# deleted the file where output is still being redirected

Tags: linux, bash

I have ran a program for some days redirecting its output to a log file, like this:

```
~$ myprog > LOG
```

By mistake, i have deleted the LOG file and i cannot see the LOG progress anymore. I have tried making the log file again with

```
~$ touch LOG
```

However it did not work. The program is still running and will run for 2 more days so there is still some LOG to come that is worth to see.

Is there any way to see the output under this problem?

Update: This is the output of lsof -p [pid]. The folder where LOG was is the first entry /home/cristobal/potts_exacto/pfamilyd-1.0.0

```
cristobal@fdyn-1:~$ lsof -p 18510
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  cwd    DIR                8,6        0  8126487 /home/cristobal/potts_exacto/pfamilyd-1.0.0 (deleted)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  rtd    DIR                8,5     4096        2 /
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  txt    REG                8,6   329460  8126501 /home/cristobal/potts_exacto/pfamilyd-1.0.0/bin/pfamilyd-1.0.0 (deleted)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5 67113040  6423790 /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cristobal@fdyn-1_0/3193/1/shared_mem_pool.fdyn-1
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    58296  3281676 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_rdma.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    50328  3281644 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_pt2pt.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    96656  3281624 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14648  3281687 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    23032  3281653 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sm.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10352  3281672 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14448  3281648 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_inter.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    34960  3281659 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_basic.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    50360  3281631 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_tcp.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    29624  3281661 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    16184  3281698 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_self.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    18960  3281651 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    87416  3281695 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    23080  3281662 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_dpm_orte.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    22800  3281703 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_hierarch.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14688  3281674 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pubsub_orte.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10464  3281379 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmca_common_sm.so.2.0.0
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10560  3281652 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_sm.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14632  3281665 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_rdma.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5     6248  3281658 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_fake.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14680  3281692 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_rcache_vma.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10456  3281634 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_bucket.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    52120  1969739 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    47680  1969743 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    97248  1969755 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    35680  1969737 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    18792  3281636 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    18928  3281680 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_binomial.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    66936  3281632 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    23544  3281668 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10552  3281649 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_basic.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14800  3281614 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_env.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10624  3281682 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_crs_none.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5     6160  3281689 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   105288  1969740 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    92720  1966309 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    48248  1966115 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpci.so.3.1.8
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    43976  2889513 /usr/lib/libnuma.so.1
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  1421464  2893526 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   153424  2889517 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.4.1.4
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14736  3281693 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_hwloc.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   450520  2893570 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.0.2
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    39184  2889506 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    10632  1969734 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  1595096  2893433 /usr/lib/libcln.so.6.0.2
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    14768  1969750 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  1815224  1969735 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   135366  1969744 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5    88384  1966124 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  1030512  1969746 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   962656  2888558 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  1358656  3281445 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.2
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   106024  3281449 /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1.0.1
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5  2826576  2896899 /usr/lib/libginac.so.2.1.0
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5   149280  1969747 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal  mem    REG                8,5      296  6423791 /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cristobal@fdyn-1_0/3193/1/shared_mem_btl_module.fdyn-1
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    0r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 64137792 pipe
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    1u   CHR              136,2      0t0        5 /dev/pts/2
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    2w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 64137793 pipe
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    3w   CHR                5,0      0t0     1037 /dev/tty
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    4r   DIR                8,5     4096        2 /
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    5u  0000                0,9        0     6115 anon_inode
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    6u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 64138322 socket
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    7u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 64138323 socket
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    8u  IPv4           64138325      0t0      TCP *:35872 (LISTEN)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal    9u  IPv4           64138328      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:60450->fdyn-1:37741 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   10u  IPv4           64138331      0t0      TCP *:1027 (LISTEN)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   11w   REG                8,6        5  8388683 /home/cristobal/lattices/kago_9xn/kago_9xn.slat.pfamily.mat.0
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   12u  IPv4           64138332      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:33727->fdyn-2:1024 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   13u  IPv4           64138333      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:44117->fdyn-3:1028 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   14u  IPv4           64138334      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52461 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   15u  IPv4           64138335      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41435 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   16u  IPv4           64138336      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41436 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   17u  IPv4           64138337      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57026 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   18u  IPv4           64138338      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41438 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   19u  IPv4           64138339      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57027 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   20u  IPv4           64138340      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57029 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   21u  IPv4           64138341      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57030 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   22u  IPv4           64138342      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41439 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   23u  IPv4           64138343      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57032 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   24u  IPv4           64138344      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57033 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   25w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 64137794 pipe
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   26u  IPv4           64138345      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52462 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   27u  IPv4           64138346      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52463 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   28u  IPv4           64138347      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52464 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   29u  IPv4           64138348      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57034 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   30u  IPv4           64138349      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52465 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   31u  IPv4           64138350      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41440 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   32u  IPv4           64138351      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41441 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   33u  IPv4           64138352      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-3:41442 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   34u  IPv4           64138353      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52466 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   35u  IPv4           64138354      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-4:57035 (ESTABLISHED)
pfamilyd- 18510 cristobal   36u  IPv4           64138356      0t0      TCP fdyn-1:1027->fdyn-2:52467 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Additional information: I am not sure if this may change the scenario. But the program is an MPI program (32 processes, so there are 31 other PIDs with a number close to 18510, which was the one i monitored) that has is currently running on a *screen* session. The course of events from the beginning to how i deleted the file was the following:

```
~$ cd path_to_pfamilyd-1.0.0
~$ screen -S my_screen_session 
~$ mpirun -np 32 ./myprog [args] > LOG
~$ Crtl + A + D
~$ some days layer, by mistake i did: rm -r path_to_pfamilyd-1.0.0, and installed another version.
~$ program is still running...
```

Comment: You're out of luck.  The file still exists, and is still being written to, but you have deleted the filesystem entry that identifies and locates the data.  `touch` creates an entirely new file in a different physical location.  If you have root access you may be able to play some tricks with the `/proc/[pid]/fd` entries but I've never tried this.

Comment: yes i have root access. I have just looked inside /proc/[pid]/fd and there are a lot of files as numbers and one number is a folder that leads to the file system again. Ill see what i can find, never tried this before, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution:

1. Use `lsof -p [pid]` to find out what files the process has open. Identify the fd for the file you are interested in.
2. Then `tail -f /proc/[pid]/fd/[file-descriptor]` where `[file-descriptor]` is the one you identified in step 1.

Comment: I am trying, let me give it a few tries, at the moment it is giving me a fd code "cwd" for the folder i deleted (inside is the LOG file). I have updated the OP.

Comment: This is really old, but I got this to work so I'll put this here for other people. The file descriptor is going to be 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr.

Comment: I got bash to reappend pid output to the file old log file. Try:  (while true; 
    do cat /proc/440277/fd/1 >> ./logs/3_clean.py.log1;
        sleep 300;
    done) &

Comment: This starts a new process that cats the stdout of the pid to the file 3_clean.py.log1. if you want to manage this new process add this to the end of your new script: 
# fd_pid=$!;
# echo $fd_pid;
# kill $fd_pid;
# mine is: 499586; # kill obviously kills the process

Answer (score -4):

Kindly Check for the path you provided in the bash script. Usually '>' redirection sign has multiple functions and is also used to create new files. Accidentally if you deleted the file it will be again created at the defined path upon next run in the script given valid permissions are there in place. But you will not be able to recover your old logs before deletion. New logs will be present at the newly created log file.

You may use append redirection '>>' instead of direct redirection to prevent previous data loss because '>' truncates the old file everytime script is run.

You may also use other search commands like locate, find etc giving date time criterion if you missed the log file path anyway.

Also try adding "> /dev/null 2>&1 &" for backed log progression at the end of command script in crontab if scheduled at particuler time.

Comment: While this may all be true, it does not address the OP's question at all.

Comment: thanks for the comments, but the problem is about recovering the output (at least from now and on) while the program is still in progress.